# combine selection with custom column value

Tags: php, mysql

In column `status` there are this values: `slider` - `sidebar` - `below` - `oncheck` - `later`.

I want to get list of all items but firstly with `status` = `slider` then `sidebar` and so on.

Each `status` group should be ordered by `date desc`.

I tried with `UNION`

```
$sql = "select * from posts where status = 'slider' union
        select * from posts where status = 'sidebar' union
        select * from posts where status = 'below' union
        select * from posts where status = 'oncheck' union
        select * from posts where status = 'later'
        order by date desc";
```

Result - items are messed (firstly `below` then `slider` then again `below` etc)

Any help?

Comment: Why don't you run each query alone?

Comment: @Mehdi, what about performances if each query is run alone?

Comment: Well TBH, multiple queries will run slower than one query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MySQL FIELD() function:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'slider', 'sidebar', 'below', 'oncheck', 'later');
```

This will sort the rows as you want :)

Comment: excellent, it works, thanks a lot, but how to order them by `date` also

Comment: @puerto Go on. You can figure it out.

Comment: @puerto just add `, date desc` between `)` and `;`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
ORDER BY FIELD (status, 'slider', 'sidebar'),date desc;
```

Please check thisone.

Comment: I tried and result is also messed. There is no difference comparing to my query.